# elasticsearch - multiple index search returning unexpected results

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I need a bit of help deciphering whats going on with my ES setup. Basically, I have created multiple indices using custom analyzers (one for each language we support) and with mapping at index time, for each client we have. The problem come in at search time, when I do a search across all of a clients' indices, one particular index (English) always ranks higher than other languages, even though the term searched appears fewer times in that English-indexed document.

So here's what I have in my ES setup:
We have multiple clients, and each client can upload documents in multiple languages. So, to accommodate this requirement, I have setup the indices named according to the clientId and language, i.e. A-en, A-de, A-fr, B-en, B-it etc (where A and B are client id's, and the -xx is the ISO language code). Each index is created with the custom analyzer for that client's required language(s) and each field is mapped to use these custom analyzers in the setting section as follows:
Here is an English index setting that all clients with an 'English' document will be indexed with:

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 5,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        },
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "english_keywords" : {
                    "type" : "keyword_marker",
                    "keywords" :  ["_none_"]
                },
                "english_stop" : {
                    "type" : "stop",
                    "stopwords" :  ["_none_"]
                },
                "synonym_filter" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "expand" : 1,
                    "synonyms" :  ["_none_"]
                },
                "english_stemmer" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "language" : "english"
                }
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "lens-english" : {
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["english_keywords", "lowercase", "english_stop", "english_stemmer", "synonym_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
    "video" : {
        "properties" : {
            "Attributes" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "ClientId" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "Comments" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-english"
            },
            "Continent" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "CountryOfOrigin" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "CreatedDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "Description" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-english"
            },
            "DescriptionEnglish" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
            },
            "DislikesCount" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "EnglishTranscription" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
            },
            "Favourite" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "FromProject" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "IsSearchable" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "LanguageISOCode" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "LanguageOfOrigin" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "LikesCount" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "NativeTranscription" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-english"
            },
            "ObjectId" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "Published" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "Recommendations" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "Status" : {
                "type" : "long"
            },
            "Tags" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-english"
            },
            "Title" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-english"
            },
            "TitleEnglish" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
            },
            "TranscriptionStatus" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "UploadSource" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "VideoImage" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "no"
            },
            "ViewCount" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "WatchLater" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "ExternalMetadata" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                    "Filters" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "ProjectId" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "Roles" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

And here is a Turkish index for those clients that have Turkish documents requiring indexing...

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 5,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
        },
        "analysis" : {
            "filter" : {
                "turkish_stop" : {
                    "type" : "stop",
                    "stopwords" : "_turkish_"
                },
                "synonym_filter" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" :  ["_none_"]
                },
                "turkish_lowercase" : {
                    "type" : "lowercase",
                    "language" : "turkish"
                },
                "turkish_keywords" : {
                    "type" : "keyword_marker",
                    "keywords" :  ["_none_"]
                },
                "turkish_stemmer" : {
                    "type" : "stemmer",
                    "language" : "turkish"
                }
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "lens-turkish" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["apostrophe", "turkish_lowercase", "turkish_stop", "turkish_keywords", "turkish_stemmer", "synonym_filter"]
                },
                "folding" : {
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "asciifolding"],
                    "tokenizer" : "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
    "video" : {
        "properties" : {
            "Attributes" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "ClientId" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "Comments" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-turkish"
            },
            "Continent" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "CountryOfOrigin" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "CreatedDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "Description" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-turkish"
            },
            "DescriptionEnglish" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
            },
            "DislikesCount" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "EnglishTranscription" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
            },
            "Favourite" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "FromProject" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "IsSearchable" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "LanguageISOCode" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "LanguageOfOrigin" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "LikesCount" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "NativeTranscription" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-turkish"
            },
            "ObjectId" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "Published" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "Recommendations" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "Status" : {
                "type" : "long"
            },
            "Tags" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-turkish"
            },
            "Title" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "lens-turkish"
            },
            "TitleEnglish" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "english"
            },
            "TranscriptionStatus" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "UploadSource" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "VideoImage" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "no"
            },
            "ViewCount" : {
                "type" : "double"
            },
            "WatchLater" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "ExternalMetadata" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                    "Filters" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "ProjectId" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "Roles" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

All language indices follow this pattern (we have 24 different supported languages), and each client will use one of these settings when creating indices, and when indexing documents into those indices.

So, all this seems fine and ES is happy with this. Now comes to the search query, and this is where things get confusing.

My search query is based on a requirement that states 'phrases must take precedence over individual terms'. Also, When a client performs a search, that search must be performed across ALL their documents and languages (hence why indices are created with the client id in the name). This is accomplished by using a wildcard in the url for the index name, i.e. /A-*/video/_search will search for all client A documents regardless of language.

Here is the search query I POST to the server...

```
POST /5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-*/video/_search
{
 "from": "0",
 "size": "1000",
 "query": {
   "template": {
     "query": {
       "filtered": {
         "query": {
           "bool": {
             "must": [
               {
                 "multi_match": {
                   "query": "{{query_string}}",
                   "type": "most_fields",
                   "fields": [
                     "Title^3",
                     "Description^2",
                     "TitleEnglish",
                     "DescriptionEnglish",
                     "EnglishTranscription",
                     "NativeTranscription",
                     "Tags",
                     "Comments"
                   ],
                   "tie_breaker": 0.1, 
                   "minimum_should_match": "70%"
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         },
         "filter": {
           "bool": {
             "must": [
               {
                 "term": {
                   "IsSearchable": true
                 }
               },
               {
                 "term": {
                   "Private": false
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       }
     },
     "params": {
       "query_string": "Turkish"
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Notice that I'm searching for the word 'Turkish', and searching across ALL languages. Now look at the results, and notice that the *-en indices return higher ranking than the *-tr (Turkish) indices which contain the word 'Turkish' more times through-out the documents fields.

```
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 15,
      "successful": 15,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 7,
      "max_score": 0.21282451,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-en",
            "_type": "video",
            "_id": "561bd2b274cbe0123c099ace",
            "_score": 0.21282451,
            "_source": {
               "CountryOfOrigin": "United Kingdom",
               "Continent": "Europe",
               "LanguageOfOrigin": "English",
               "LanguageIsoCode": "en",
               "Title": "Nikes",
               "TitleEnglish": "Eng video Eng lang",
               "Description": "izlemek",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "",
               "VideoImage": "ff3a093a-700e-4c53-94df-cc5eb425c043_Image.jpg",
               "ViewCount": 9,
               "LikesCount": 0,
               "DislikesCount": 0,
               "CreatedDate": "2015-10-12T15:33:05.634Z",
               "WatchLater": [],
               "Favourite": [],
               "Status": 2,
               "TranscriptionStatus": 6,
               "UploadSource": 3,
               "IsSearchable": true,
               "FromProject": false,
               "NativeTranscription": "",
               "Tags": [
                  "Turkish",
                  "Nike"
               ],
               "Comments": [],
               "Attributes": [],
               "Recommendations": [],
               "ClientId": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95",
               "Private": false,
               "ObjectId": "561bd2b274cbe0123c099ace"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-en",
            "_type": "video",
            "_id": "5617cb8b74cbe2110890820b",
            "_score": 0.19917427,
            "_source": {
               "CountryOfOrigin": "Armenia",
               "Continent": "Europe",
               "LanguageOfOrigin": "English",
               "LanguageIsoCode": "en",
               "Title": "English Video",
               "TitleEnglish": "English Video",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "",
               "VideoImage": "df80412b-d6b9-4104-932b-c8e44b005fb2_Image.jpg",
               "ViewCount": 16,
               "LikesCount": 1,
               "DislikesCount": 0,
               "CreatedDate": "2015-10-09T14:13:30.893Z",
               "WatchLater": [],
               "Favourite": [],
               "Status": 2,
               "TranscriptionStatus": 5,
               "UploadSource": 3,
               "IsSearchable": true,
               "FromProject": false,
               "NativeTranscription": "",
               "Tags": [
                  "Turkish",
                  "Purple Aki"
               ],
               "Comments": [],
               "Attributes": [],
               "Recommendations": [],
               "ClientId": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95",
               "Private": false,
               "ObjectId": "5617cb8b74cbe2110890820b"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-en",
            "_type": "video",
            "_id": "561bb49e74cbe002f09301fa",
            "_score": 0.17025961,
            "_source": {
               "CountryOfOrigin": "United Kingdom",
               "Continent": "Europe",
               "LanguageOfOrigin": "English",
               "LanguageIsoCode": "en",
               "Title": "Mark's Transcription Test",
               "TitleEnglish": "Mark's Transcription Test",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "",
               "VideoImage": "09c6d366-6807-4d9d-9588-fd4730907b9b_Image.jpg",
               "ViewCount": 6,
               "LikesCount": 0,
               "DislikesCount": 0,
               "CreatedDate": "2015-10-12T13:24:45.833Z",
               "WatchLater": [],
               "Favourite": [],
               "Status": 2,
               "TranscriptionStatus": 6,
               "UploadSource": 3,
               "IsSearchable": true,
               "FromProject": false,
               "NativeTranscription": "",
               "Tags": [
                  "turkish",
                  "mark",
                  "Watch"
               ],
               "Comments": [],
               "Attributes": [],
               "Recommendations": [],
               "ClientId": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95",
               "Private": false,
               "ObjectId": "561bb49e74cbe002f09301fa"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-tr",
            "_type": "video",
            "_id": "5617c97c74cbe21108908205",
            "_score": 0.12725623,
            "_source": {
               "CountryOfOrigin": "Turkey",
               "Continent": "Asia",
               "LanguageOfOrigin": "Turkish",
               "LanguageIsoCode": "tr",
               "Title": "Turkish Video - Under 10mins - Request Trans",
               "TitleEnglish": "Turkish Video - Under 10mins - Request Trans",
               "Description": "Turkish  - Request Trans",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "Turkish  - Request Trans",
               "VideoImage": "ba4341e5-7af8-418e-91e3-818e290a0989_Image.jpg",
               "ViewCount": 21,
               "LikesCount": 0,
               "DislikesCount": 0,
               "CreatedDate": "2015-10-09T14:04:44.033Z",
               "WatchLater": [],
               "Favourite": [],
               "Status": 2,
               "TranscriptionStatus": 5,
               "UploadSource": 3,
               "IsSearchable": true,
               "FromProject": false,
               "NativeTranscription": "",
               "Tags": [],
               "Comments": [
                  "Turkish",
                  "Liverpool"
               ],
               "Attributes": [
                  "5617c80974cbe211089081fd_3_2",
                  "5617c80974cbe211089081fe_4_1"
               ],
               "Recommendations": [],
               "ClientId": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95",
               "Private": false,
               "ObjectId": "5617c97c74cbe21108908205"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-tr",
            "_type": "video",
            "_id": "5617ca3574cbe21108908208",
            "_score": 0.07719648,
            "_source": {
               "CountryOfOrigin": "Argentina",
               "Continent": "South America",
               "LanguageOfOrigin": "Turkish",
               "LanguageIsoCode": "tr",
               "Title": "Turkish Video - No Trans",
               "TitleEnglish": "Turkish Video - No Trans",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "",
               "VideoImage": "735f0c09-3c1c-415e-870f-70f18be632ea_Image.jpg",
               "ViewCount": 14,
               "LikesCount": 0,
               "DislikesCount": 0,
               "CreatedDate": "2015-10-09T14:07:49.705Z",
               "WatchLater": [],
               "Favourite": [],
               "Status": 2,
               "TranscriptionStatus": 0,
               "UploadSource": 3,
               "IsSearchable": true,
               "FromProject": false,
               "NativeTranscription": "",
               "Tags": [
                  "Turkish"
               ],
               "Comments": [],
               "Attributes": [],
               "Recommendations": [],
               "ClientId": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95",
               "Private": false,
               "ObjectId": "5617ca3574cbe21108908208"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-de",
            "_type": "video",
            "_id": "5617c8ca74cbe211089081ff",
            "_score": 0.015614418,
            "_source": {
               "CountryOfOrigin": "Germany",
               "Continent": "Europe",
               "LanguageOfOrigin": "German",
               "LanguageIsoCode": "de",
               "Title": "German Video - Under 10mins - With SRT",
               "TitleEnglish": "German Video - Under 10mins - With SRT",
               "Description": "German Video\nTag: Oct 9",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "German Video\nTag: Oct 9",
               "VideoImage": "04bf4827-3459-41f6-9fc0-7003dfe7ea5d_Image.jpg",
               "ViewCount": 5,
               "LikesCount": 0,
               "DislikesCount": 0,
               "Published": "2015-10-09T14:03:01.066Z",
               "CreatedDate": "2015-10-09T14:01:46.517Z",
               "WatchLater": [],
               "Favourite": [],
               "Status": 2,
               "TranscriptionStatus": 5,
               "UploadSource": 3,
               "IsSearchable": true,
               "FromProject": false,
               "NativeTranscription": "Ich denke, dass Nachhaltigkeit sich darum dreht,Verpackungen zu reduzieren oder Energie, die bei der Produktion entsteht,zu verringern oder auch lokal zu produzieren,um die CO2-Bilanz zu reduzieren.Ich glaube, dass sich viele Verbraucherbeim Einkaufen über Nachhaltigkeit Gedanken machen,was letztendlich auch beeinflusst was sie kaufen,vor allem aber würde ich von mir als Verbraucherin behaupten,dass ich mich an die Firmen halte, die die gleichen Wertebezüglich Nachhaltigkeit haben wie ich.Ich gehe gezielt in Geschäfte, die weniger Verpackung benutzenoder solche, die man einfacher recyclen kannund wenn wir können, gehen wir immer zu Fuß zu regionalenoder lokalen Geschäften, wenn sie in der Nähe sind.Und viele Unternehmen versuchen die gleichen Produktefür einen niedrigeren Preis zu verkaufen,aber wenn eine Firma mich überzeugen kann, dass ihre Produkte nachhaltiger sindoder sicherer für mich und meine Umwelt,wäre ich am Ende auch bereit, mehr zu bezahlen.Wenn ein Unternehmen behauptet, nachhaltig zu sein,will ich immer herausfinden auf welche Art und Weisesie sicherer sind.Es gibt so viele Öko-Zertifikateund ich weiß nicht was die bedeutenoder ob sie wirklich für Nachhaltigkeit stehen.Vielleicht könnte es einen Beschluss geben,der es den Verbrauchern einfacher macht,nachhaltige Produkte zu verstehen, das wäre für alle eine große Hilfe.",
               "EnglishTranscription": "I think that sustainability turns about, Packaging to reduce or energy generated in the production, to reduce or even locally to produce, to reduce the CO2 footprint. I think that to many consumers worry buy about sustainability, What ultimately affects what you buy but above all, I would argue by me as a consumer, that I the companies consider myself, the same values as I have with regard to sustainability. I'm specifically going to shops that use less packaging or such which is easier to recycle can and if we can, we go to regional always walking or local shops if they are nearby. And many companies are trying the same products for sale, for a lower price But if a company can convince me that their products are more sustainable or safe for me and my environment. would I also be willing to pay more at the end. If a company claims to be sustainable. will I always find out in what way they are safer. There are so many eco-certificates and I don't know what you mean or whether they really are for sustainability. Perhaps there could be a decision, Consumers easier makes it,. understanding sustainable products that would be a great help for everyone.",
               "Tags": [
                  "Oct 9",
                  "Turkish"
               ],
               "Comments": [],
               "Attributes": [
                  "5617c80974cbe211089081fd_3_2",
                  "5617c80974cbe211089081fe_4_4"
               ],
               "Recommendations": [],
               "ClientId": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95",
               "Private": false,
               "ObjectId": "5617c8ca74cbe211089081ff"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95-tr",
            "_type": "video",
            "_id": "561b860d74cbe0103cf23369",
            "_score": 0.011710813,
            "_source": {
               "CountryOfOrigin": "Turkey",
               "Continent": "Asia",
               "LanguageOfOrigin": "Turkish",
               "LanguageIsoCode": "tr",
               "Title": "izlemek Nike",
               "TitleEnglish": "Demo 4",
               "Description": "izlemek Nike",
               "DescriptionEnglish": "Demo 4",
               "VideoImage": "97e66fe2-6f62-4a43-b234-0abda414dedf_Image.jpg",
               "ViewCount": 17,
               "LikesCount": 0,
               "DislikesCount": 0,
               "Published": "2015-10-12T10:07:52.281Z",
               "CreatedDate": "2015-10-12T10:06:05.015Z",
               "WatchLater": [],
               "Favourite": [],
               "Status": 2,
               "TranscriptionStatus": 5,
               "UploadSource": 3,
               "IsSearchable": true,
               "FromProject": false,
               "NativeTranscription": "Şimdi makyaj masamın başına geçtimVe makyajımı yapmaya başlayacağımÖncelikle güzel bir baz süreceğimSmashbox'ın Photo Finish bazını kullanacağımÖnce göz makyajımı yapacağımBugün böyle altın ve siyah tonlarındaya da altın kahve tonlarında bir makyaj yapmayı planlıyorumÇünkü, giyeceğim bir ceket varCeket de altın zincirler ve altın detaylar taşıyorEe tabii, söz konusu altın olduğu zamanAltın ve bronz ve doğal tonlar olduğu zamanNaked paletimden elimi çekemiyorumEe tabii far kullanacaksam, bir far bazı kullanmadan olmazUrban Decay far kullanacağım içintesadüfen Urban Decay'den primer potion göz bazını kullanacağımŞu kadar miktar benim için yeterliBeni biraz böyle nefes nefese vehani koşturur vaziyette görebilirsinizÇünkü birazcık acelem varVe hazır böyle güzel bir saç makyaj gibi bir şey planlıyorlenNeden videosunu çekmeyeyim, diye düşündüm",
               "EnglishTranscription": "Now I take over my dressing table And I'm going to start doing my makeup First of all, I'm going to drive a beautiful base Smashbox's Photo Finish base to use First, I'm going to do my eye makeup Today in shades of gold and black or I'm planning to do a makeup in shades of gold and coffee I'm going to wear a coat, because there Jacket in gold chains and gold carries the details So of course, when it comes to gold When gold and bronze and natural hues I can't get my hand off my naked palette So of course I use a headlight headlights not without some Urban Decay eyeshadow I use for Incidentally, I'm going to use from the Urban Decay primer potion eye base This quantity is enough for me That's me a little breathless and you know, the one you can see running condition Because it's a little bit of a hurry And such a beautiful something like hair make-up ready planned yorlen Why is the video I thought, that I may not",
               "Tags": [
                  "test tag",
                  "turkish",
                  "mark",
                  "izlemek",
                  "Purple Aki"
               ],
               "Comments": [],
               "Attributes": [
                  "5617c80974cbe211089081fd_3_1"
               ],
               "Recommendations": [],
               "ClientId": "5617c3c867567a0b0c570a95",
               "Private": false,
               "ObjectId": "561b860d74cbe0103cf23369"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Can anyone who knows what to look for have an eyeball at this and see if there is something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Term frequency is only a part of how relevance is calculated - inverse document frequency and document length also matter. In your examples, English documents rank higher because 1) they're shorter, and 2) the English index contains fewer mentions of term "Turkish", making each document that does have that term rank higher.

Comment: is there any way I can prove that this is the case?

Comment: Yes - try adding very similar documents into English and Turkish indexes, with the only difference being how frequently they use keywords such as "English" or "Turkish". With that, the "Turkish" documents should be ranked higher. You can try using Elasticsearch explain API to troubleshoot ranking issues: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Comment: I did try what you suggested and it seemed to make no difference. However, I found that if I remove the '"tie_breaker":0.1'  parameter, then it seems to work! There seems to be a big change in the calculations that 'explain' returns when it is removed. Any ideas why? I kinda need the tie_breaker for the phrase searches, but can be removed if it is the culprit.